# Most efficient way to get information from a seed

Tags: php

This is a simplified example. But concept remains the same.

In this example I want to let the user input a seed (123) and it will always generate the same conditions from the seed. Ie:

```
<?php
mt_srand(123);
$weather = ['sunny','rainy','foggy','snowy','windy'];
shuffle($weather); // [ snowy , windy , sunny , rainy , foggy ]
print_r($weather[0]); // snowy 
?>
```

But if a year from now I decide to add a new type of weather (in this example, 'tornado'), all the old seeds will no longer generate the same (as expected). Ie:

```
<?php
mt_srand(123);
$weather = ['sunny','rainy','foggy','snowy','windy','tornado'];
shuffle($weather); // [ rainy, snowy , sunny , foggy, tornado , windy ]
print_r($weather); // rainy
?>
```

Currently, I have the database set up so it will save the weather condition ('snowy') and any other parameters it generates with the seed.  But this feels extremely inefficient, not to mention having the possibility of becoming extremely bloated if you add hundreds of options generated by the seed.
I considered saving a 'version number' as well as a seed, and it would only load parameters based on the version number, but that also seems like it could get very bloated. Essentially I'm wondering how bigger companies do it? For example versions of Minecraft had an option to input a seed and it would generate the world exactly the same every single time.